# Is there a term for 'a three-syllable word with stress on the second syllable'? (Or similar)

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun to describe a word by its number of syllables and the location of its stress.

Saying that it's a "trisyllabic word with penultimate stress" feels like too much work.

i.e., *"The word 'gazebo' is a **blank**."*

If anyone knows of other terms, such as a two-syllable word with stress on the first syllable or a two-syllable word with stress on the *first* syllable.

Are words even classified on this level?

Comment: The other terms you mention tangentially are trochee: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trochee and iamb: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iamb_(poetry).  Relevant mandatory [xkcd link](https://xkcd.com/856/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Words whose stress is on the penult are called [*paroxytone*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/paroxytone) words per Oxford Dictionaries Online.

Since this can be used as both an adjective and a noun, you are talking about *trisyllabic paroxytones*. I normally use the *-ic* version for the adjective, so *paroxytonic*.

There are also [*oxytonic*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oxytone#English) words stressed on the last syllable and [*proparoxytonic*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proparoxytone#English) words stressed on the antepenultimate syllable.

Answer (score 4):

Amphibrach.

"Gazebo is an amphibrach" i.e. it has three syllables and has its stress on the second/middle syllable.

"Elephant is a dactyl" and "Employee is an anapest".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibrach

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *[amphibrach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibrach).*

According to Wikipedia, "in English accentual-syllabic poetry, an amphibrach is a stressed syllable surrounded by two unstressed syllables." I'm not sure if it is used outside of poetic contexts, though. An amphibrach does not have to be a single word, and its boundaries don't have to correspond to word boundaries.

It's one of many such terms taken from the names given to [metrical feet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_(prosody)) in antiquity. Another one, the *bacchius,* is mentioned in the answer to the following question: [What is the name of a particular poetic foot, unstressed, stressed, stressed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184446/what-is-the-name-of-a-particular-poetic-foot-unstressed-stressed-stressed)

Comment: Annoyingly enough, [amphibrach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_(prosody)) is not [autological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word).